# Error with Sharp Architecture Tasks Layer: Command handler not found for command type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, cqrs, sharp-architecture

I am currently using Sharp Architecture 2.0 and have been doing pretty well with it.  But I am coming on an issue with Performing commands in the Tasks layer. I have the following classes associated with my Command:

***SaveOptionStep1Command*** which implements ***CommandBase*** and
***SaveOptionStep1CommandHandler*** which implements
***ICommandHandler< SaveOptionStep1Command >*** and
***SaveOptionStep1CommandResult*** which implements ***CommandResult***

When I create the command, I get the below error and cannot determine where the issue is coming from.

**ERROR**
**Command handler not found for command type:** EasyOptions.Tasks.Commands.SaveOptionStep1Command

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** SharpArch.Domain.Commands.CommandHandlerNotFoundException: Command handler not found for command type: EasyOptions.Tasks.Commands.SaveOptionStep1Command

Here is a Githubu Gist of my code: https://gist.github.com/1314136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was creating the Repositories incorrectly.  I was creating my repositories with my ClientRepository class instead of accessing it using the interface IRepositoryWithTypedId.  Once I changed that my Repositories and Handlers were correctly added to my Windsor Container without any dependency issues. It is now working as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with SharpArch 2.0.4.
After spending a couple of hours playing with the ComponentsRegistars.cs for Castle components registration, I figure out the that I need to modify the AddTasksTo method. 
My viewpoint is that since Commands are mainly placed in Infrastructure, they replace the old version of:

```
     container.Register(
        AllTypes
            .FromAssemblyNamed("v2.Tasks")
            .Pick().If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Tasks"))
            .WithService.FirstNonGenericCoreInterface("v2.Domain"));
```

with this :

```
 container.Register(
    AllTypes
        .FromAssemblyNamed("v2.Tasks")
        .Pick()
        .WithService.FirstNonGenericCoreInterface("v2.Domain"));
```

which eventually will pick each and every element, I think.

So, by using the first version, the problem solved.

Thanks